# C Client doesn't receive the message server sends

Tags: c, client-server

I am just writing a simple test program to get familiar with client server implementation with c. My expected output is the following:
for client:

```
Hello message sent
Hello from server
```

However, I am getting the following output:

```
Hello message sent
```

**The client waits for a message to receive but never gets it. I don't know how to fix this problem.**

Here is the code I ran.

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define PORT 8080 

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{ 
        int sock = 0, valread; 
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
        char *hello = "Hello from client"; 
        char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
        if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)  
        {   
                printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
                return -1; 
        }   

        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
    
        // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form 
        if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0) 
        {   
                printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n"); 
                return -1; 
        }   

        if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)  
        {   
                printf("\nConnection Failed \n"); 
                return -1; 
        }   
        send(sock , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 );  
        printf("Hello message sent\n"); 
        valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024); 
        printf("%s\n",buffer );  
        return 0;    
}
```

server.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PORT 8080 

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
        int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
        struct sockaddr_in address;
        int opt = 1;
        int addrlen = sizeof(address); 
        char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
        char *hello = "Hello from server"; 
    
        // Creating socket file descriptor 
        if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)  
        {   
                perror("socket failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR , &opt, sizeof(opt)))
        // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
        {
                perror("setsockopt");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        address.sin_family = AF_INET;
        address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        address.sin_port = htons( PORT );

        // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
        if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                                                                sizeof(address))<0)
        {
                perror("bind failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0)
        {
                perror("listen");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                                        (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
        {
                perror("accept");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024);
        printf("%s\n",buffer );
        send(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 );
        printf("Hello message sent\n");
        return 0;
}
```

I have also tried using recv instead of read and the same problem persist.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Ok, what is displayed at the server?

Comment: @MartinJames The server displays both expected outputs and closes. Hello from client
Hello message sent

Comment: @Arkku no.  read() will return with a result > 0 if any data is received.

Comment: @MartinJames Ok, I trust you to remember the API better. And, actually, the code shown here works just fine for me, i.e., the expected output is printed.

Comment: You could try closing the sock in the server before terminating.  It's at least possible that the data I/O request generated by the send() call is flushed from the system, as the server process is exterminated, before the data is actually sent? (guessing now:)

Comment: I mean, it's usual to wrap the accept() etc. in a while(true) loop so that the server does not terminate after one peer exchange:)

Comment: You expect to read 1024 bytes, but you send only about 5 bytes from the server, so it will just block and wait for the rest of the bytes.

Comment: @Devolus that's not true; the result of `read` is there for a reason. (it's not being used by the client, but that doesn't mean it wouldn't be accurate). Something else is wrong. And I'm in Arku's camp: the code as-is posts the desired output and both processes terminate thereafter as expected. Personally I find it aromatic that neither are checking their io results correctly, nor closing their descriptors before shutdown, but it should still work.

Comment: @MartinJames I closed the sockets and reran and the problem still persists. First, I reran after closing the server socket. Then, I also closed the closed the client socket and reran. I didn't see the second output for client.

Comment: @ManojAdhikari ok, I am stuck now:(  If it was I, I would next resort to wireshark to determine if the server sent anything.

Comment: Did you disable firewall code on your client?

Comment: @stark lol, good guess, I bet you're right...

Comment: Owait....it's on the local stack...

Comment: @MartinJames How do you mean? Will you please help me understand this?

Comment: firewall is turned off, firevault is on in my computer

Comment: So, this code worked fine when I created a new user account on my mac and ran it there. Not sure why it doesn't work on my initial account despite having the firewall turned off.